# Override selectInput values using check box

Tags: r, shiny

I am struggling to find the right terms to google on this one. I have a Shiny app with two slider bars that provide input values to the server portion of the app. I would like the user to have the option to adjust the slider bars (scenario A) OR instead check a box/click a button that would take them straight into scenario B. Scenario B would have set inputs that the user doesn't need to know.

If we use this an an example, the addition would let a user check a box that says, "I don't want to choose." If we set the default to MN, checking the box would result in a result that says "You chose MN".

```
if (interactive()) {
  
  # basic example
  shinyApp(
    ui = fluidPage(
      selectInput("variable", "Variable:",
                  c("Cylinders" = "cyl",
                    "Transmission" = "am",
                    "Gears" = "gear")),
      tableOutput("data")
    ),
    server = function(input, output) {
      output$data <- renderTable({
        mtcars[, c("mpg", input$variable), drop = FALSE]
      }, rownames = TRUE)
    }
  )
  
  # demoing group support in the `choices` arg
  shinyApp(
    ui = fluidPage(
      selectInput("state", "Choose a state:",
                  list(`East Coast` = list("NY", "NJ", "CT"),
                       `West Coast` = list("WA", "OR", "CA"),
                       `Midwest` = list("MN", "WI", "IA"))
      ),
      textOutput("result")
    ),
    server = function(input, output) {
      output$result <- renderText({
        paste("You chose", input$state)
      })
    }
  )
}
```

Comment: Please post a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with checkbox to select scenario A or B.

Comment: @YBS, that is exactly what I don't know how to do.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are looking for this.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    useShinyjs(),
    checkboxInput("wanttochoose", "I don't want to choose", value = FALSE),
    sliderInput("slide1", "My value", min=0, max=10, value=3),
    selectInput("state", "Choose a state:",
                list(`East Coast` = list("NY", "NJ", "CT"),
                     `West Coast` = list("WA", "OR", "CA"),
                     `Midwest` = list("MN", "WI", "IA")), 
                selected = "MN"
    ),
    textOutput("result")
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$result <- renderText({
      paste("You chose", input$state)
    })
    observe({
      if (input$wanttochoose){
        shinyjs::show("slide1")
      }else{
        shinyjs::hide("slide1")
      }
      
    })
  }
)
```